# Pass URL to as $routeParam in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

#### How can I pass actual URL (with slashes, commas, etc.) as a $routeParam to AngularJS App?

this will work:
http://paprikka.github.io/le-bat/#/preview/asdadasda

this won't:
http://paprikka.github.io/le-bat/#/preview/http://page.com

neither will this:
http://paprikka.github.io/le-bat/#/preview/http%3A%2F%2Fpage.com

or this:
http://paprikka.github.io/le-bat/#/preview/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpage.com

#### Details

AngularJS routing mechanism by its design does not allow to pass strings with slashes as query parameters. I can understand the reasoning behind this decision - we don't want to create a stateless server here.

However, there are still cases when using different separators or regular expressions in routes might be necessary.

I wanted to create an app that takes a url hash string parameter and loads its content to an iframe ([link here](http://paprikka.github.io/le-bat/)). Routes are set up in pretty standard way (I'm using Coffeescript, but this snippet does not differ from pure js):

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/preview/:src', {templateUrl: 'partials/preview.html',
  controller: 'PreviewCtrl'})
  .when('/preview', {templateUrl: 'partials/preview.html',
  controller: 'PreviewCtrl'})
```

Of course, I can load url from hash before AngularJS gets bootstrapped and then pass it to the library, but it would be nice if I could also update current route parameter when changing data in scope - that's why I think it's much better not to avoid AngularJS API.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what was the question?

Comment: Hm.. I've updated the question with a more terse description of the problem. Take a look at the link I've added (hopefully, this won't be treated as spam:))

Comment: Couldn't you just use query-param style encoding? Like `http://example.com/#/preview/?url=http://page.com`. See also: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams

Comment: Well, I wouldn't ask if I could:) Did you check the demo?
And, of course - I've read the docs.

Comment: Ah right of course, that's the problem here! Have you tried escaping the url with `encodeURIComponent`? Results in something like `http://example.com/#/preview/?url=http:%3A%2F%2Fpage.com`

Comment: Ok so I guess that doesn't work either :/

Comment: Yes, this was the first think I though of:( slash escaped to `%2F` will break routing as well. On the other hand `%20` will get passed.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is ultra-clear now, only a solution is missing :)

Comment: @RafalPastuszak Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to achieve something similar.

Comment: Not one I've tested. But after some time spent with angular I've come with a rather simple idea: you could transform url fragment with your own service before it gets parsed via $location and $routeParams and remove conflicting characters, eq. `#/http://paprikka.pl` would be #/url=paprikka.pl. Then, you could create a rule for things beginning with `url=` in the $routeProvider config. I'll check that soon in practice and let you know:)

Comment: @Jascination, I've posted an answer with Plunkr. Let me know if it works in your case:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to find a solution working with current stable version (@1.0.7).

Current way of handling this problem will involve $route-related events, parsing angular-incompatible urls on the fly and handling them via an additional service working in a similar way as $http interception.

You can see working code examples here: http://embed.plnkr.co/fIA2xj/preview

### Main steps

1. pass an angular-incompatible url as usual, eg. go to site.com/url/http://site.com
2. listen to a $routeChangeStart event and extract correct url parameter for paths beginning with `/url/`
3. encode the correct url parameter to an angular-compatible form (in this particular case, I use base64). Don't use encodeURIComponent, because angular will treat as any other url
4. redirect to another route with your business logic, eg. site.com/parsed-url/BASE64_GOES_HERE
5. decode the URL in the controller and use it as usual :)

### Code

#### Create angular app module as usual

```
angular.module('routes',[]).config([

  '$routeProvider',

  function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/test', {templateUrl: 'test.html'})
      // This one is important:
      // We define a route that will be used internally and handle 
      // parameters with urls parsed by us via the URLInterceptor service 
      .when('/parsed-url/:url', {templateUrl: 'url.html', controller:'URLCtrl'})
      .when('/', {redirectTo: '/test'})
      .otherwise({templateUrl: '404.html'});

  }

])
```

#### URL Interceptor service (singleton)

```
.service('URLInterceptor', function($rootScope, $location){
  // We listen to $routeChangeStart event and intercept it if 
  // the path matches our url scheme. In this case, every route
  // beginning with /url/ will be caught
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(e, next, current){

    // $location.path does change BEFORE actual routing happens,
    // so in this case we get parsed new location object
    // for free.

    // To be hones, a better way of handling this case might be using 
    // $locationChangeStart event instead, but it would require us to parse urls 
    // manually.
    var path = $location.path();
    // check if string begins with '/url/'
    var matcher = path.slice(0,5);
    var cleanPath = '';
    if (matcher === '/url/'){
      // Yes it does, yay!
      // Remove leading '/url/' to extract the actual parameter
      cleanPath = path.slice(5);
      // Encode our url to a safe version. We know that encodeURIComponent won't 
      // work either, so a good choice might be base64.
      // I'm using https://code.google.com/p/javascriptbase64/downloads
      $location.path('/parsed-url/' + Base64.encode(cleanPath));
      // Prevent default event execution. Note that, it won't cancel related $location Events
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  return {
    decode: Base64.decode,
    encode: Base64.encode
  }
})
```

#### Controllers

```
// Main application controller
// We instantiate our URLInterceptor service here
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope, $location, URLInterceptor){
  $scope.navigateTo = function (path) {
    $location.path('/url/' + path);
  }
})
.controller('URLCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, URLInterceptor){
  $scope.url = URLInterceptor.decode($routeParams.url);
});
```

### Two things you should remember:

1. Although I tried to create a solution as clean as possible, usually passing the data this way to angular isn't considered a good practice, so try not to use it unless you really need to.
2. You can handle this issue with only one route. I just find it cleaner this way.

Comment: base64 doesnt support japanese characters so im looking for another encoding format.

Answer (score 17):

Using [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider) in Angular 1.2, you can pass in a url if it's at the end of the path by adding an asterik to the pattern. The following should work whether or not you URLComponentEncode the url.

The route:

```
angular.module('angularApp', ['ngRoute'])
      .when('/frame/:picture_url*', {
        templateUrl: 'views/frame.html',
        controller: 'PictureFrame'
      });
```

The controller:

```
      .controller('PictureFrame', function($scope, $routeParams, $sce){
        //whitelist the URL
        $scope.picture_url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($routeParams.picture_url);
      });
```

Then in your template:

```
<iframe ng-src="{{picture_url}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The route still does not match when passing a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution but I don't know if it will help you. From Angular documention http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location $location has a function search(search, paramValue)

To pass the parameter:

```
parameter = encodeURIComponent url
$location.search({ yourURLParameter: parameter }).path('/preview')
```

To read the parameter:

```
url = decodeURIComponent $location.search().yourURLParameter
```

Of course you need to inject $location dependency

Comment: Thanks, but we've tested encodeURIComponent and it din't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have mixed search params with routes. Your search needs to come before your routes.. specifically for older browsers.    I think ie7 blows up if its not `url/?search/#/hash`

Try this format:

```
domain.com/?my=params&another=param/#/my/hashes
```

Comment: That's cool, but search and routing is done by the front-end. I'm sorry but I had to downvote your answer :(

Someone suggested using query-style params in url fragments, but it's not a good idea as well. Anyway, thanks for taking your time.