# Bootstrap Switch stops working with Angular Routing

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started learning Angular and have set up Angular routing for my first app.

I have a shell page and some sub pages, for example products.html, help.html etc

the sub pages contains forms with bootstrap switches and validation, which for some reason stops working (the switch is rendered as a regular checkbox and validation does not run - please note that I am not using Angular JS).

However, if a place the same code directly in the shell page it works fine.

How do I get the sub pages to behave exactly like they the code in the shell page?

Basically, if I have the following code in a form in one of my subpages help.html:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="active">My checkbox<br />
            <div class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="active" name="active">
            </div>
        </div>
```

...the switch does not render correctly, but if I move the code directly to the shell page it renders correctly.

So what is the difference in what happens in the sub page (which is shown in a  on the shell page) or somw code that is placed directly in the shell page HTML.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so that we can see what you have tried till now

Comment: I tried to set up a jsfiddle, but although I include all external libraries I don't get it to work. Also, I don't know how to place several HTML files there. Here is the non working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yto2wpf9/ I also edited my original post. Please note that I am building an app for a specific web site which uses their own framework based on twitter bootstrap, so I am forced to use their built in validation etc. My question is really how to get the code in a sub page to behave in the same way as the one placed in th shell page (because that works fine)

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you are using [this Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) plugin.

I am also assuming that you are initialising the switches that work on the shell page by doing something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch();
});
```

The problem with this is that it will only apply the bootstrap switch plugin to the checkboxes that it finds on the first page load, not after you change pages within an `ng-view` element.

What I recommend you do instead is to create a simple AngularJS directive to apply the bootstrap switch plugin to the checkboxes. The reason this will work is that Angular will compile the contents of a view every time you change pages and the `link()` functions of all the directives found will be run. Thus, your checkboxes, if they use this new directive, will always have the plugin applied correctly.

The directive could be as simple as:

```
app.directive('bsSwitch', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      $(element).bootstrapSwitch({
        onSwitchChange: function(event, state) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(state);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Then change your markup in the views to be:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="active">My checkbox</label>
    <br />
    <div class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="active" name="active" bs-switch>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If you wish to apply the bootstrap switch to *all* checkboxes on the application without the need for additional attributes, you could instead create a directive that will apply to all `<input>`s, and then just check if they are checkboxes.

Like so:

```
app.directive('input', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        if (attrs.type === 'checkbox')
          $(element).bootstrapSwitch({
            onSwitchChange: function(event, state) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(state);
              });
            }
          });
      }
    }
});
```

And then you can omit the `bs-switch` attribute in your markup.

See my [working Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5SJqsYnszO3SSK2FB25?p=preview) (Plunkr is a better tool than jsFiddle for Angular examples, and allows you to create multiple HTML, CSS and JS files).

**EDIT 2:** As Mark pointed out, it was broken if the checkbox was initially checked. Here is a fixed version of the directive (and an [updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GJSfmeepjDejy6MqbvAa?p=preview)):

```
// As an element directive that will apply to all checkbox inputs:
// <input type="checkbox" ng-model="blah">
app.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      if (attrs.type === 'checkbox' && !Object.hasOwnProperty(attrs, 'bsSwitch')) {
        $(element).bootstrapSwitch({
          onSwitchChange: function(event, state) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(state);
            });
          }
        });

        var dereg = scope.$watch(function() {
          return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        }, function(newVal) {
          $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state', !! newVal, true);
          dereg();
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You are probably right. Where do I put the directive? didn't get it to work. I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". However, I used the switch as an example and I would like to avoid to have a lot of hacks here and there to get things to work properly. I have also discovered that the validation plug in does not work either and since I am working towards a custom framework (although based on bootstrap) it is hard to overlook which problems I might run into later. So I am trying to find a setup for my app that will be more solid in the long run.

Comment: I edited my answer to incorporate what I believe you are trying to accomplish. I also fixed the errors in my initial directive code and linked to a working example on Plunkr.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works, but in my environment it behaves slightly different, probably because it is a customized version of bootstrap (I am building the app for a specific environment and are forced to use their setup). Seems like Angular Routing will get me in this kind of problems (I also have problems with jQuery validation) etc. Is it much more ineffective to use tabs instead of routing? Is there a way to pass simply pass a parameter to another tab, lets say if I have a list of products and I want to open the "editProduct" tab and get info in the DB about productID 123?

Comment: That sounds like a different question to me. As a general rule on StackOverflow, questions should be specific and on one topic, with as much code as required to demonstrate the problem. If you have other questions, post them as new questions. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answers that work, too. If you post a new question with more details, I _may_ be able to help, but I'm not sure I can.

Comment: Yes, I started another question about that. I really appreciate your help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383120/using-tabs-instead-of-routing-in-angular

Comment: Nice solution, unfortunately the directive doesn't initialize the switch to true if the model is initially set to true

Comment: @Mark Well observed! I edited my answer to include a fix for this issue and forked the Plunkr with the fix for both versions of the directive.

Comment: @GregL thanks for taking the time to look at the Plunk, when I set showSectionTwo to true it is still initialised to off for some reason

Comment: @Mark Damn, you're right. I had one final crack at it, this should be much better now.

Comment: +1 Its not clear if the 3rd version is a corrected version of the 1st or 2nd versions (I guess its the second after rereading it).   I'm probably missing something here but If any of the versions aren't correct, it would be less confusing if they were edited out rather than keeping them visible in a manual edit history... oh yeah, nice job!